# Third-Party-Cookies Tracking - Google Chrome

Tags: cookies, chrome, tracking

I've read an article about third-party-cookies which explained that in Google Chrome disabling third-party-cookies will not stop the browser from sending third-party-cookies. So when I visit Facebook every day and get first-party-cookies from them, they can still track me in the internet although I've disabled third-party-cookies.

At first I couldn't believe that, but I have checked the HTTP-headers and the cookies were sent to Facebook. Firefox doesn't send third-party-cookies.

What can I do about it? Is a trackingblocker like Ghostery the only way to protect myself from being tracked?

Answer (score 1):

I just tested that Chrome option and it seems to work for me. But if it doesn't for you, the next best thing would indeed be using something like [Ghostery](https://www.ghostery.com/) or  [EFF's Privacy Badger](https://www.eff.org/privacybadger)

In fact, I'd probably suggest using one of these tools anyway. Because rather than blocking ALL third-party cookies (some are useful!), they only block requests to domains that are actually using them to track you.